# How to update the size of stackView after adding subviews (programatically)?

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5, uistackview, cgrect

```
let innerView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
let outerSV = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [innerView])
    
outerSV.frame.width // still 0! should be 50
outerSV.frame.height // still 0! should be 50
```

So the question is: how to update the size of stackView after adding subviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `sizeToFit()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` on the subviews of the stackView. Constrain the UIStackView as you normally would, and constrain the subviews as you normally would.

Also, you need to have it set to Fill Proportionally and it will resize to fit the new content.

And Make sure you don't have a bottom constraint of a height constraint on the stackview. You should only need left, right and top constraint.

Comment: Everything sounds reasonable, but it doesn't work. I also called sizeToFit() and layoutIfNeeded() functions. But I called it on StackView. Doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Roman Could you show your constraint settings ?

Comment: I don't have any constraints. All code is in the question :)

Comment: You must place top, leading and trailing constraints to stackView to make that work correctly

Comment: But I don't want to imbed this StackView anywhere. I will not show it to the user. My purpose is to build StackView programatically, fill it with subviews and make a "snapshot" of this hole thing (a UIImageView). And I can do it, if I set the size of the StackView by hand, by myself. But I want make it to infer the size from subviews!

Comment: Okey, basically you say that it's impossible. And looks like it's the correct answer  Thank you. I will assign the size by hand 